# no of records in a store are not returning in extjs

Tags: extjs, global-variables, local-variables

I am new to extjs and was working on creating a dynamic screen depending on the no of records from the Ext.data.store(); getTotalCount/getCount are used to get the no of records from the store. I need to store the total no of records in a var and return it

I am trying to do something like this

```
function Get_count()
{  
     var num;                            
     CacheStore.on({

           'load':{

            fn : function(store,records,options){
                    num = getTotalCount();
                    //console.info('Store count = ', tsize);
                    //console.info(' count = ', getCount());
            },
            scope: this
    },
    'loadexception' : {
            fn : function (obj,options,response,e){
                    //console.info('error = ', e);
            },
    scope : this
    }

});

     // this is a wrong logic but have to do something similar 
    //return num;  //return num 

    };
    tsize  = Get_count();
```

I always get null in tsize. I also tried getCount() instead of getTotalCount() butI am getting the same problem.

dont know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is a bit poked here. You can't fire a function that will add a listener to a store that will hook when the store has finished loading. ( well you can, but this is a subtle bug down the line ).

What you need to do is declare a listener on the store when you create it, that contains the function you wanna use the number in.

```
cacheStore =Ext.create...
cacheStore.on('load',function(store,records,e){
    //dosomestuff that needs the count
    var num=  store.totalCount()
    //now you use the num in here, else you create an async error

    //or you can ...
    my.someFunc(num); 
    //in here, but you can only run it after the store has loaded
},this);
```

Comment: Hi alex I tried using that but I am getting the error " null is null or not an object "